# QtDesigner custom widget

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

Good day,

1. I`m coding my QtDesigner plugin. According to the official doc
   I created **Collection** subclass of **QDesignerCustomWidgetCollectionInterface** and implemented
   separated plugins for each widgets throught subclassing of  **QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface**.
   I have done it sucsessfully and have *.dll plugin.
   I copy it in the correct \plugins\designer folder.
2. Because I`m working under Windows and use prebuil QtCreator by msvc2015
   I have to recompile my QtCreator from source with a given *mingw* compiler.
   I\'ve done it sucsesfully. Now I can run my recompiled QtCreator from *cmd* with correct environment.
3. After all these troubles I can run *QtCreator-mingw* and see plugins in a designer pallete
   and drag-drop its to *.ui.
   I can edit **Q_PROPERTY** attribures through designer.

My problem is following:
  - After drag-drop I see widget as wrote before (3);
  - After close *QtCreator-mingw* and reopen it in the *.ui file
  I couldn`t see *MyWidget* and couldn`t edit **Q_PROPERTY**.

Note:
  - I use wizard of user custom Qt Designer and **Collection** was generated automatically.
  - The same for widget plugins.
  - I just edited **doXml** method.
  - I can`t see widget in design-mode but compilation and running are done. All MyWidget are there.

Does anybody know what is the root of my problem?

Comment: please provide more code, to start with your `doXml` function

Comment: I mistyped, not **doXml** but **domXml** and content is like in [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-customwidgetplugin-example.html). I have the behavior in Designer.

Comment: and what does the function `name` return? Does it match with what is in the `domXml`?

Comment: Function `name` returns *AnalogConponent*. But my widget place in a namespace `gui::iocomp`. So, when I changed `name` returned value all works perfect and I can reopen IDE with same result.

Answer (score 0):

Function `name` returns `AnalogConponent`. But my widget place in a namespace `gui::iocomp`. So, when I changed name returned value to `return gui::iocomp::AnalogConponent` and append similar construction to the `domXml` function all works perfect and I can reopen IDE with same result and see correct description of **Q_PROPERTY** in designer (before they changed to dynamic options).

I think that official doc lost this aspect.